# A form with jQuery UI tabs, PHP and a back function

Tags: php, jquery, forms, user-interface, tabs

I've read several posts, but seem to have a problem in understanding...

- In one of the tabs I've got a form -- ok
- This form will be server validated with php -- ok
- If no errors occur - the user has the possiblities to finally send the form -- ok
- New function: If no errors occur - the user has also the possibility to go back and change entries -- not ok

First I tried something like

```
echo '<input type="button" class="submit" value="make changes" name="back_button" onClick="history.go(-1)">';
```

Will go to the wrong tab and clears the form in the correct tab...

The form values are "sticky" like

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($email)){echo $email;} ?>" />
```

which did work for now.

The form is in the 5th. tab which I can address with something like that:
$tabs.tabs('select', 4);

How should my JS code look and were should I include it in my php-file and how do I bind it to my "back-button"?

Update:
On the final page the user can see the entered values and decide to send them finally or go back and change them. But the go back part is not working.

Update 2:

```
<form method="post" action="team.php#tabs-sign_in">
```

Update 3:

Sorry for confusing:
Will go to the wrong tab and **does not clear** the form in the correct tab... which is okay. The data is still there but the user will see the wrong tab.

Update 4:

Just came up with something like that, which won't work...

```
<a href="#" onClick='history.go(-1);$("#tabs").tabs("select","4");'>modify</a>
```

Can anyone explain me why this won't work?

Comment: i think the whole problem is in your button.  How are you sending/saving the data?  If you go back without saving the data anywhere then your form field values will be lost

Comment: so you should have defined an `action` which is the page you are directed to when you click a submit button.  As far as I can see you do not have a submit button.  The web page defined in your `action` should store all your variables somehow.  If you do not define an action for your form.  The submit button will just direct to your web root.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may find using sessions useful. Save the data to a session for future editing.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Or if you have a user login mechanism, it may be better to save the form state in your database to be edited / updated at a later date.

Comment: It's not meant for future edition etc. it's meant only for the "just in time" processing

Comment: I agree with your saving the form on the database end, putting anything on the session is usually difficult to manage and not really regulate, so someone could have set the same session variable as you and now you either corrupt that variable's data, or your may not have the right value.

Comment: Essentially if you want the user to be able to go back and update / edit the entries then they need to be stored somewhere. You can use a session, or possibly bounce these values back 'n forth on the request (get / post). The latter being prone to more issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use javascript to store most of your client side data and manipulation. And use ajax to post the data to your server, so you don't need to page refresh, and your back and forward between tab would not need a page loading, nor need a history

edit
Switch between tab would mean show and hide different preloaded div's

Comment: This is a already running project with about 35 forms. I want to avoid to change the whole form handling, only for a "back"-function...